# Is "afin" ever used on its own in a sentence?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, conjonctions

That is, without being followed by "de" or "que"?

Comment: Do you have examples that we could work with? Otherwise, they look inseparable, as Luke was saying: http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/afin%20de.

Comment: No Frank, that is why I asked ;D

Comment: I voted not to close because, it may be obvious for french expert but this is still a valid question. If you want to close, please say why. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Afin is short for "**à fin**" or "**avec pour finalité**" (litterally : with the goal). Saying it alone, without "de" or "que" would be like saying "**dans le but de**" without "de", or "with the goal" without "of".

Comment: Merci beaucoup Jylo ! Ton explication est très claire.

Answer (score 1):

**afin est toujours suivi de de + infinitif ou afin que + locution conjonctive**

comme déjà indiqué: contraction de à fin (finalité): mais ceci ne se dit pas.

On peut dire aussi : ***à cette fin***. Cela suppose que cette fin (finalité) a déjà été décrite.

Comment: Merci Guillaume. Votre explication est très claire.

Answer (score 0):

No, those two expressions are invariable. (See e.g. [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/afin#Conjonction).)